# Hover on legend and hover on path effect in nvD3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 for creating visualisation in my project.
I have to create multiple different kind of charts including line chart.
This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ykga1jqw/

My code:

```
  // Line chart begins here

  var temperatureIndexJSON = [
    {
      key: "Average temp.",
      values: [{ "x": 1998, "y": 0.45 }, { "x": 1999, "y": 0.48 }, { "x": 2000, "y": 0.5 }, { "x": 2001, "y": 0.52 }, { "x": 2002, "y": 0.55 }, { "x": 2003, "y": 0.58 }, { "x": 2004, "y": 0.6 }, { "x": 2005, "y": 0.61 }, { "x": 2006, "y": 0.61 }, { "x": 2007, "y": 0.61 }, { "x": 2008, "y": 0.62 }, { "x": 2009, "y": 0.62 }, { "x": 2010, "y": 0.62 }, { "x": 2011, "y": 0.63 }, { "x": 2012, "y": 0.67 }, { "x": 2013, "y": 0.71 }, { "x": 2014, "y": 0.77 }, { "x": 2015, "y": 0.83 }, { "x": 2016, "y": 0.89 }, { "x": 2017, "y": 0.95 }]
    }
  ];

    nv.addGraph(function () {
      var chart = nv.models.lineChart() // Initialise the lineChart object.
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true); // Turn on interactive guideline (tooltips)
    chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('TimeStamp (Year)'); // Set the label of the xAxis (Vertical)
    chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Degrees (c)') // Set the label of the xAxis (Horizontal)
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f')); // Rounded Numbers Format.
    d3.select('#averageDegreesLineChart svg') // Select the ID of the html element we defined earlier.
        .datum(temperatureIndexJSON) // Pass in the JSON
        .attr('class','line-testing')
        .transition().duration(500) // Set transition speed
        .call(chart); // Call & Render the chart
      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update); // Intitiate listener for window resize so the chart responds and changes width.
      return;
    });
```

I want to change stroke width when user hovers on legend or path itself.
Similar effect as in these 2 links:

https://jsfiddle.net/ymavtsbj/11/

http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070123

I tried checking nvd3 but since it's documentation is not well defined and no such examples are available, so far I haven't got a solution. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `legendMouseover`, `elementMouseover` events as follows:

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendMouseover', function(e) {
  d3.select('path.nv-line').attr('stroke-width', 4);
});

chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementMouseover', function(e) {
  d3.select('path.nv-line').attr('stroke-width', 4);
});
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ovvn/gr2wb8cs/27/)

Comment: Thank you Osman, I got that.
I think when we create multiple lines, in that case also we can refer individual lines in same way as: d3.select('path.nv-line.SOME_OTHER_CLASS').
Then, we can change svg property of individual line as you said.

Comment: Yeah, for multiple lines it would be something like `d3.select('.nv-series-1 path.nv-line')`